# Redis | redis-cli INFO / avg_ttl value

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, nosql

When I run the command `redis-cli INFO`, one of the returned values indicates the `avg_ttl`. I'm unsure what unit of time this is represented in?

Example:

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=706818,expires=228745,avg_ttl=1521990750
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a bit confusing indeed.

- the TTL command return value is in seconds
- PTTL command return value is in milliseconds
- avg_ttl from INFO is in milliseconds

Also, note that this average value avg_ttl is just an estimate based on random check of keys.

Comment: what's mean of avg_ttl = 0 ?

Comment: avg_ttl = 0 means none of the sampled records had an expiration (ttl) set.